# Is there a way to do two different functions?

Tags: jquery, javascript

For an example, if I want the user to do both click and keypress that will give the same output. I would not like to have two of the same codes.

If I had something like

```
$('#next').click(function(){
 // code goes here
});
```

I would like to also implement this

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

that will be part of the click. Any suggests? Thank you!!

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles, please. You've done it with almost all of your questions. :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to write it as a tag, I just thought that it will give people a better understanding as to what kind of language I need help on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function myFunc() {
   alert("left pressed");
}

$("#next").click(myFunc);

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) myFunc();
});
```

You could also have myFunc() handle both events like so..

```
function myFunc(e) {
    // First we check to see if this event has a keyCode property
    // If so, then we need to check the value of that keyCode.
    // If it doesn't match the value we're trying to capture,
    // then we just "exit" the function by returning false.
    if(e.keyCode && e.keyCode != 37) {
        return false;
    }

    alert("left pressed");
}

// Since myFunc() handles both scenarios, we can 
// bind it to both objects.
$("#next").click(myFunc);
$(document).keypress(myFunc);
```

Comment: +1 to both of you for beating me to it. I blame my time on waiting for a live example =P

Comment: Bloody hell you guys answer fast!

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
function clicky(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('do stuff');
}

$('#next').click(clicky);
$(document).keydown(clicky);
```

you want to write the function and call it later

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mPhAZ/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the common code in a separate function and call from within your selector functions? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

So:

```
function doSomeStuff() {
    // common code here
}


$('#next').click(function() {
    doSomeStuff();
});


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        alert("left pressed") ;
        doSomeStuff();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       $('#next').click();
    }
});
```

.click() is a standard javascript function that can be used to simulate clicking a button.

Comment: if it's a javascript HTMLElement method (which it is), why are you calling it through jQuery?